# Using scala.sys.process with timeout

Tags: scala, processbuilder

I find it extreemly cool to use [standard syntax](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) like

```
import scala.sys.process._
    val countLogger = ProcessLogger(line => {println ("out line: " + line)},
                                 line => {println ("err line: " + line)})

    val exitCode = ("cat prog.c" #&& "gcc prog.c -o prog -lm" 
            #&& "echo running, this may hang" #&& "prog.exe") ! countLogger

    println("exitCode = " + exitCode)
```

It however happens that last process hangs. Is it possible to kill it on timeout?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can wrap your process in a `Future(blocking(_))` and if it doesn't return after the time-out, you call `process.destroy()`.

That's what I have done for my small [Processor library](https://github.com/Sciss/Processor), e.g. [see here](https://github.com/Sciss/Processor/blob/master/src/main/scala/de/sciss/processor/impl/ProcessWrapper.scala). Instead of using `!` to eagerly wait for the exit-code, you use the `run` method. Here is an adaption from the README:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.sys.process._

val p = "sleep 100".run()               // start asynchronously
val f = Future(blocking(p.exitValue())) // wrap in Future
val res = try {
  Await.result(f, duration.Duration(2, "sec"))
} catch {
  case _: TimeoutException => 
    println("TIMEOUT!")
    p.destroy()
    p.exitValue()
}
```

Comment: I have edited your question to demonstrate how to use this techinique with multiple commands and output capture. It works. Nevertheless, this article says that using `Await.result` is worse than not using Futures at all. Can you say why this does not apply in our case?

Comment: Well, the idea of futures is to let them do whatever they do asynchronously. So `Await` is kind of counter-intuitive. But if you want a time-out, that's the way to solve it, while still playing nicely with futures. In the real scenario you wouldn't block your main thread with `Await` but wrap that in a `Future` as well and that would be the actual future result to use in your main logic. Instead of returning the `exitValue` in the time-out case, you could re-throw the time-out exception. For example, in my Processor library, calling `abort` will complete the future with `Processor.Aborted`.

Comment: Hey, this solution works fine but it also throws `java.lang.ThreadDeath` in the caller thread when calling `destroy()`. Isn't there any issue with that? Why does it try to kill the caller thread and not simply the spawned process?